# MS Access SQL Update table a based on Value in table b joined by ID

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access

I am having an issue to make an update query making the update based on values other table. The problem is also that the other table has a To Many relation with the one I try to update.

Table A

```
ID   isTrue  hasOption1 hasOption2 hasOption3
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
```

Table B

```
ID          OptionType
1           type1
1           type2
2           type2
1           type3
2           type1
6           type3
```

The Update needs to set in table A whether the ID has Any option, and set Y or N for the optionTypes like the below;

Table A after update:

```
ID   isTrue  hasOption1 hasOption2 hasOption3
1    Y         Y          Y          Y
2    Y         Y          Y          N
3    N         N          N          N
4    N         N          N          N
5    N         N          N          N
6    Y         N          N          Y
7    N         N          N          N
```

It is probably a matter of syntax which I don't know for example how to make Update with a Join. Or would it be simpler to do several queries in VBA?

Answer (score 1):

This Query is for Sql Server same will also work in MS Access.

```
update TableA set   isTrue= case when (B.OptionType='type1') then 'Y' else 'N' end, 
                hasOption1=case when (B.OptionType='type2') then 'Y' else 'N' end,
                hasOption2=case when (B.OptionType='type3') then 'Y' else 'N' end,
                hasOption3=case when (B.OptionType='type4') then 'Y' else 'N' end from TableA AS A  inner join tableb As B on A.ID=B.ID
```